# Django gives 400 Bad request error in image upload using ajax

Tags: django, image-uploading, bad-request, quill

I am using quill editor to upload an image and the an ajax function is used to send the image to views.py.

This is the python function for uploading the image.

**views.py**

```
def upload_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES.get('file'))
        return HttpResponse("Successful")

    return HttpResponse("Failed")


def handle_uploaded_file(file):
    with open('upload/', 'wb+' ) as destination:
        for chunk in file.chunk():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

This is the ajax request:

```
function upload(file, callback) {
    console.log('called');

      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', file);
      $.ajax({
         url : '{% url 'dashboard:upload_image' %} ',
         type : 'POST',
         data : formData,
         contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
         headers: { "X-CSRFToken": $.cookie("csrftoken") },
         processData: false,
         success: function(data) {
            console.log('success');
            callback(data.url)
         }
      });
   }
```

Function calling upload() :

```
function(value) {
              let fileInput = this.container.querySelector('input.ql-image[type=file]');
              if (fileInput == null) {
                fileInput = document.createElement('input');
                fileInput.setAttribute('type', 'file');
                fileInput.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
                fileInput.classList.add('ql-image');
                fileInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
                  if (fileInput.files != null) {
                    upload();
                  }
                });
                this.container.appendChild(fileInput);
              }
              fileInput.click();
            }
        }
```

Comment: could you show the ajax request for image upload?

Comment: added that. @FazilZaid

Answer (score 0):

Error in string

```
with open('upload/', 'wb+' ) as destination:
```

Wrong path. Set the file name.